Zoom with React + Next.js - Example implementation
Next.js + React with Zoom updated for 2024, this post seeks to solve the integration problem that I ended up wasting time finding the complete solution. Here is an example implementation of the integration:
Feel free to suggest improvements or add constructive comments
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export function ZoomComponent() {
  const meetElementRoot = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const ZoomEmbed = await (await import("@zoomus/websdk/embedded")).default;

      const client = ZoomEmbed.createClient();

      if (meetElementRoot.current && client) {
        await client.init({
          language: "pt-PT",
          zoomAppRoot: meetElementRoot.current,
        });

        const signature = ""; //signature_response_zoom: https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/auth/
        const meetingNumber = "";

        await client.join({
          signature,
          sdkKey: process.env.zoomSDKKey,
          meetingNumber,
          userName: "Jhon Doe",
          success: (success) => {
            console.log(success);
          },
          error: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          },
        });
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return <div ref={meetElementRoot}></div>;
}

Post dedicated just to solving a problem that was not so clear to find
